# Dynamic Content Holder in Adobe Business Catalyst?

Tags: html, business-catalyst

I've got html for a header that needs to go on all pages of an Adobe Business Catalyst site that I'm building, however, the header needs to change which menu item is bolded depending on the page it's on. I don't want to use a Menu because I've already created the html code for the entire header. Putting the code in a Content Holder seems like the best choice, but is there a way for me to insert the content holder into pages but tell it which item to mark as selected?

Answer (score 1):

A link to the site would be handy.

If you can't provide a link (due to non-disclosure or other reason) you can achieve what you've asked to by adding an id to each menu item that is the page ID of the page that each menu item is linking to.

Example

```
<li><a href="/" id="HOMEPAGEID"></li> 
<li><a href="/about" id="ABOUTPAGEID"></li>
```

Then, in your template - add 
 
    `<style type="text/css">
    #{module_oid} {font-weight:bold;}
 </style>`

This needs to be in the either the template, or you can put it in the contentholder, because the {module_oid} tag will not render correctly as the current page ID within your stylesheet, it must be an internal style.

This is not the best solution, you should really convert to a dynamic menu using the menu version 2
info here: menu-module-v2 tutorial http://helpx.adobe.com/business-catalyst/partner/menu-module-v2.html
if converting the menu is a time concern you can try this out: faster-way-to-build-bc-menu  http://www.thrise.com/blog/faster-way-to-build-bc-menu.htm (be warned this is experimental and sometimes requires more fixing).

Answer (score 0):

I think in bc you are able to just use a CSS to achieve that just add a **:active** to the menu class every time the link of your menu is clicked it will load the new content and possibly passing the active link to state active. it works better if you use a single template for various pages but worth a test.